# Are trigraph substitutions reverted when a raw string is created through concatenation?

Tags: c++, c++11

It's pretty common to use macros and token concatenation to switch between wide and narrow strings at compile time.

```
#define _T(x) L##x
const wchar_t *wide1 = _T("hello");
const wchar_t *wide2 = L"hello";
```

And in C++11 it should be valid to concoct a similar thing with raw strings:

```
#define RAW(x) R##x
const char *raw1 = RAW("(Hello)");
const char *raw2 = R"(Hello)";
```

Since macro expansion and token concatenation happens before escape sequence substitution, this should prevent escape sequences being replaced in the quoted string.

But how does this apply to trigraphs? Are raw strings formed through concatenation with normal strings still subject to having their trigraph substitutions reverted?

```
const char *trigraph = RAW("(??=)");      // Is this "#" or "??="?
```

Comment: How long does it take to try this in a compiler, vs. the time spent asking the question here?

Comment: I'm not looking to use it in production code, I'm writing a compiler and it seems like an edge case. Besides, I'm not aware of any compiler with complete C++0x support (and I don't think the final standard has even been published yet).

Comment: @Damien that's not an appropriate answer... Compilers for C++ are know to diverge form the spec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, the trigraph is not reverted in your example.**

`[lex.phases]p1` identifies three phases of translation relevant to your question:

> 1. Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations.
>   3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens.
>   4. Macro invocations are expanded.

Phase 1 is defined by `[lex.trigraph]p1`. At this stage, your code is translated to `const char *trigraph = RAW("(#)")`.

Phase 3 is defined by `[lex.pptoken]`. This is the stage where trigraphs are reverted in raw string literals. Paragraph 3 says:

> If the next character begins a sequence of characters that could be the preﬁx and initial double quote of a raw string literal, such as R", the next preprocessing token shall be a raw string literal. Between the initial and ﬁnal double quote characters of the raw string, any transformations performed in phases 1 and 2 (trigraphs, universal-character-names, and line splicing) are reverted.

That is not the case in your example, therefore the trigraph is not reverted. Your code is transformed into the *preprocessing-token* sequence `const` `char` `*` `trigraph` `=` `RAW` `(` `"(#)"` `)`

Finally, in phase 4, the `RAW` macro is expanded and the token-paste occurs, resulting in the following sequence of *preprocessing-tokens*: `const` `char` `*` `trigraph` `=` `R"(#)"`. The *r-char-sequence* of the string literal comprises a `#`. Phase 3 has already occurred, and there is no other point at which reversion of trigraphs occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Trigraph substitution happens before macro processing.

UPD Please disregard this. I haven't realized that c++0x reverts trigraphs in raw string literals.

UPD2 2.5.3 describes the process of forming raw-string-literal preprocessing tokens. Trigraph reversal is a part of this process. There are no raw-string-literals which are not preprocessing tokens. So the answer to your question seems to be yes.

Comment: I understand that the substitution happens before macro processing, but the standard refers to trigraph substitutions being /reverted/ for raw string literals. Since the raw string literal is only formed later on (as a result of concatenation), I'm curious as to whether that's still the case.